# Node MCU Esp12-E does not support server accept function

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, esp8266webserver

I am trying to get a web server to run on the ESP12E on the Node MCU variant, and following the example from the esp8266 documentation page [here](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/server-examples.html). But the code does not compile, throwing the following error message:

```
'class WiFiServer' has no member named 'accept'; did you mean '_accept'?
```

I'm relatively new to MCUs in general, and cannot find a solution for this on any website. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The 'latest' documentation applies for git master branch.

`accept()` is ready for the next release of Arduino esp8266. It will be version 3.1.0. Until then you can use `server.available()`. It works the same way as `accept()` in ESP8266WiFi library's WiFiServer.

I initiated the addition of `server.accept()`, because `server.available()` in esp8266 WiFiServer works as Ethernet library's `server.accept()`, not as `server.available()`.